# Nested interrupts in unicore processor?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduled-tasks, interrupt-handling

Assuming a least priority interrupt has occured on a unicore processor.

Which leads to the execution of the ISR by disabling the current IRQ.
Mean-while a high priority interrupt occured.

Will the current ISR will get pre-empted and control will be given to high priority ISR ?

If yes then after serving high priority ISR will the control be given back to low priority ISR ?

If interrupt is served after disabling the scheduler then who will take care of switching of low priority ISR to high priority ISR.. vice versa. ?

Comment: AFAIK, Whether the current ISR get pre-empted depends on the Pre-empt setting of the kernel. A scheduler is not required for switching to ISR and between ISRs. Even if the ISR is pre-empted, the new ISR would be using the same stack, so the control should come back to the first one automatically. The section about interrupt stack in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/kernel-stacks might be helpful.

Comment: In recent kernels, ISRs always run with interrupts disabled on the local CPU that is running the ISR. There used to be a flag `IRQF_DISABLED` that could be passed to `request_irq` to control whether interrupts should be enabled during the ISR, but that has been a no-op since kernel 2.6.35, and was finally removed in kernel 4.1.